# setTimeout() having no effect

Tags: javascript

I have a silly page where a link will trigger a POST request for a long running task. So the page will have to poll another endpoint for status. Here is the actual code:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  function check_status(id) {
    alert(id)
  }

  $(function() {
    $("a#save_preview").bind('click', function() {
      $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/api/v1.0/creatives/" +
        $("img#preview").attr("creative_id"),
          {}, function(data, status) {
            alert(status);
            setTimeout(check_status(100), 8000);
        }, "json");
    });

  });
```

So the stubbed check status is supposed to be called 8 seconds after the POST request succeeded. However, whenever I run this code, it's called right afterwards. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `setTimeout(check_status(100), 8000);` should be `setTimeout(check_status, 8000, 100);` or perhaps use an anonymous function if you need to support below Internet Explorer 10 like `setTimeout(function(){check_status(100);}, 8000);`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a callback **function** to the `setTimeout` method but instead of providing it, you are directly calling it `check_status(100)`, so nothing is actually getting called after timeout. You can change in this way:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    check_status(100)
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to have a function inside setTimeout
The below code should work in your case

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  function check_status(id) {
    alert(id)
  }

  $(function() {
    $("a#save_preview").bind('click', function() {
      $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/api/v1.0/creatives/" +
        $("img#preview").attr("creative_id"),
          {}, function(data, status) {
            alert(status);
            setTimeout(function(){check_status(100);}, 8000);
        }, "json");
    });

  });
```